# In TFS, is there any way to identify from a work item when a commit associated with it was released?

Tags: tfs

TFS **16.131.27701.1**

Working from a Release, a user can quickly find references to the Work Items included in that release, and a user can reference the Commits included within that Release.

Working *from* a Work Item or a Commit, is there any way to quickly find the Release that included it that delivered it to an environment?

Comment: No not really. The REST API allows you to query the build that include the commit and the releases that ship this exact build, but I suppose your question is from the UI. It remains a very difficult question for a number of reasons. One being that the term Environment is actually not reflecting reality in many cases, it's more like a Phase or a Stage or a Step in the pipeline.

Comment: In Azure DevOps you can connect the Release to Work Items (like Biuld), but in TFS 2018.2 is not available :/